# "pi pi-chevron-up" in ui timepicker not showing any icon to change time interval. Insted is should show "fa fa-angle-up"

Tags: calendar, primeng

Below Code is not showing icon to change time interval, it automatically added the class "pi pi-chevron-up" that does not show any icon.

> 

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your primeng version, if it's `6.0.x` then change it to `^5.2.7` in package.json. And reinstall NPM module `npm install`.

Comment: Thanks, Aman , thanks you very much, you shaved my life.प्यार का शुक्रिया कुछ इस तरह अदा करू
आप भूल भी जाओ तो मे हर पल याद करू
प्यार ने बस इतना सिखाया हे मूज़े
की खुद से पहले आपके लिए दुआ करू..!!

Comment: @PawanParashar bhai ye Stackoverflow hai Facebook nahi :D :D :D

Answer (score 1):

Here's my fix: open src/assets/sass/theme/_icons.scss and add the missing rule, should be something like:
`&.pi-chevron-up {@include icon-override("keyboard_arrow_up");}`

After that you need to compile the theme you're using with:
`$ sass theme-indigo.scss theme-indigo.css`

Answer (score 1):

According to [Primeng >=6](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-6-0-0-beta-1-released-primeicons/) the `font-awesome` dependency is not used anymore and instead you have to install the new `npm i --save primeicons` dependency (and replace your font-awesome css imports with the new ones).